# Why do different resolutions with same aspect ratio distort the image on external display?

Tags: display, resolution, displayport, vga-adapter

I attach my MBP (OS X 10.10.4) via VGA to my tv and the aspect ratio is correct when setting an `1360x786` resolution, which is a 1.77 aspect ratio. But when trying to increase the resolution to `1690x944`, also 1.77 aspect ratio, the image is distorted. Now I wonder how that can be the case given the ratio between height and width is identical.

Comment: Are you certain you are actually getting the resolution you are asking it for? My first guess would be the TV can't cope with one of them & is actually doing something different.

Comment: No, I'm actually not sure and thought of the same. But how can I verify this?

Comment: My TV displays the resolution as it changes, but only in 'TV terms' 720i 1080p etc. Not sure how you would interrogate it, especially over VGA.

Comment: Check your settings for overscan and underscan on your TV.

Comment: Unfortunately, the UI is quite limited and contains no such settings. It's a cheap tv.